# Java: How to Concatenate a string in a loop

Tags: java

```
String disp;
for(int i=0; i<31 ; i++)
disp = disp + Integer.toString(i);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, disp);
```

ERROR GIVEN:

> Calendar.java:28: error: variable disp might not have been initialized
>   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, disp);

Comment: Change `String disp;` to `String disp = "";` or some default value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid concatenating result String in loop since it each iteration in has to create copy of old String with new part. Instead use `StringBuilder` and its `append` method.

```
StringBuilder disp = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
    disp.append(i);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, disp);
```

---

Anyway cause of your problem is that `disp` doesn't have any string assigned to it, so there is nothing to concatenate *to*. Also while concatenating to string you don't need to explicitly parse its elements to String, code responsible for that will be added by compiler. Try

```
String disp = "";//assign value to `disp`
for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
    disp = disp + i;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to mention:

- a) initialize your String:

  ```
  String disp = "";
  ```

  If you do not initialize `disp`, it is `null` and therefore may cause trouble. The compiler recognizes, that `disp` is uninitialized and therefore does not compile the program.
- b) you do not need `Integer.toString(...)`:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < 31 ; ++i) {
      disp = disp + i;
  }
  ```

  All primitives can be automatically casted to a `String`. Therefore, you can skip the cast via `Integer.toString(...)`in this case.

Final note: you might want to use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to gain some performance. Look at [Pshemo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30968449/4216641) or [Eran's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30968435/4216641) answer for details.